# Attempting to 'encapsulate' reusable javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, oop

This whole question is a sort of 'what I've tried' in an attempt to encapsulate my js, but it's not working as I'd hope.

On my page I have a div.

```
<div id='myDiv'></div>
```

I also have some script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(function () {
    $('#myDiv').hide();
  });

</script>
```

This script will grow in size and complexity, so I want it off the page and into an external js file. That's fine, but I also want it to be reusable. What the javascript will do is turn a div (and it's children) into a control (slider for example).

So after researching ways in which I can almost mimic oop principles in javascript, I've got the following in an external file:

```
var MyControl = function () {
    this.init= function (myDiv) { 
        myDiv.hide();
    };
};
```

I then call it like so:

```
$(function () {
    var myControl = new MyControl();
    myControl.init($('#myDiv'));
});
```

The problem is that the div isn't hidden despite calling hide() on it. If I debug this, I see I have the div, it's passed in fine, and hits every line of code I'd expect it to (can even display the div's type in an alert).

**Why isn't the div affected on the page?**

**Is this approach a recommended one for solving the problem I discussed at the start of this post?**

Comment: You have `myDiv` parameter and call `div.hide()`

Comment: Well spotted. It's a typo (in this question, not my actual code), I'll sort this now. Thanks.

Comment: Do you need `constructor` in your code or it could be simple `namespace`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want use that same `div` all over time you can try create your component in that way:

```
function MyControl (div) {
   this.div = div;
}

MyControl.prototype.init = function () {
   return this.div.hide();
}
```

And use it in this way:

```
var myControl = new MyControl($('#myDiv'));
myControl.init();
```

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Z7vRq/

But if you want it to be used only in `init` function try this way:

```
function MyControl () { }

MyControl.prototype.init = function (div) {
   return div.hide();
}

var myControl = new MyControl();
myControl.init($('#myDiv'));
```

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Z7vRq/1/

**Regarding to comment:**

You can try wrap all construction code into that structure:

```
var MyControl = (function () {
    function MyControl (div) {
        this.div = div;
    }

    MyControl.prototype.init = function () {
        return this.div.hide();
    }

    return MyControl;

})()
```

Comment: I like this. The only comment I have, though, is that you've brought the definition of init outside of MyControl function. The idea was to wrap all of this up, almost as though it were a class. Can this init be declared inside of MyControl? Please excuse my ignorance to what's possible in js, I come from a C# background so naturally moving towards the concept of classes and objects.

Comment: @DeeMac look at my edit. This is the closest thing that you can do, I think... JS in its root a prototypal language, so the best way you can do is to use prototypes to build controllers...

Comment: Thanks very much. Exactly what I was after.

Comment: This still isn't working. There's something else wrong with my code. You answered my question, and on your fiddle your function is able to manipulate the DOM element, my code does not.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Z7vRq/2/ - This code works here, but it doesn't in my solution. There are no errors on the page, and no styling overriding the behaviour of .hide(). What's even stranger - is that if I do this on the parent div in my code, it works. There's something about peforming this on the child. NOTE: I do have the child, the selector is fine. Thanks again for this.

Comment: I sorted it. The .children() method was not working as I'd introduced an update panel, which rendered a div as the immediate child element, meaning I had to swap children() for find(). Works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this approach a recommended one for solving the problem I discussed
>   at the start of this post?

I would recommend reading the RequireJS "[Why Modules](http://requirejs.org/docs/why.html)" and "[Why Asynchronous Module Definitions](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html)" articles for a primer on the different challenges and solutions for making modular JavaScript.